# Отступ полученных данных при scraping'e

Tags: javascript, node.js

Проблема в следующем есть блок с текстом в ктором вложен еще 1 болк с текстом, при получении данных текст сливается в одну сплошную. Возможно ли пропустить вывод вложенного **div** блока с классовым именем **text_block** ? Или же можно как-то разделить данные ?

```
<div class="text_block_in">
 <div class="text_block">Тут какой либо текст</div>Прочитать текст.</div>
```

При скрапе таким способом:

```
  request("https://site.ru/news/", (err, res, html) => {
        const htmlAll = cheerio.load(html);
        htmlAll('.info_block_line').each((i, el) => {
            const output = htmlAll(el)
                .find('.text_block_in')
                .text()
                .replace(/\s\s+/g,'');
            console.log(output);    
        }); 
    });
```

На выходе получаю такой текст:

> Тут какой либо текстПрочитать текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.text() выдает весь текст элемента, включая текст вложенных блоков.

Текст только самого элемента должен помочь выдать такой код

```
const output = htmlAll(el)
  .find('.text_block_in')
  .contents()
  .filter(function(){ 
    return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE; 
  })[0].nodeValue
```

На случай если на сервере это не сработает(т.к. клиентский код), есть более медленный вариант через jquery-like

```
htmlAll(el)
    .find('.text_block_in')
    .clone()    //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()      //again go back to selected element
    .text();
```

Comment: Davydov Большое спасибо. То что нужно было. Второй вариант подошел, первый выругался.